# program compiles very nicely but when running its drop an error at the string input

Tags: java, string, methods

program compiles very nicely but when running its drop an error at the string input in method UserInputWindows. Ive written a while loop like this before with no issues but i cant seem to understand why its giving me an error now. the program is nowhere near done, i just ran it real quick to see if i got any errors. here the coder below

```
enter code here
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PaintEstimate
{
final static double WallAndCeilingPaintCost = 18.50;//cost for 1 gallon
//final static double WhiteEnamelPaintCost = 9.50; //cost for 1 quart//using only for refrence now//changed to _MoldingCostPerQuart 
//final static double ColorEnamelPaintCost = 12.50; //cost for 1 quart//using only for refrence now// changed to _MoldingCostPerQuart
final static double CoverageOfWallAndCeilingPaint = 250.00; // coverage of wall and ceiling paint in sqft
final static double CoverageOfEnamelPaint = 100.00;// coverage of enamel paint both color and whit in linear sqft

public static double IntchesToFeet;
public static double RoomSquareFeet, CeilingSqaureFeet;
public static double InchRoomWidth, InchRoomLength, InchRoomHeight;
public static double FeetRoomWidth, FeetRoomLength, FeetRoomHeight;
public static double NumberOfWindows, NumberOfDoors;
public static double InchesWindowsHeight, InchesWindowsLength, InchesWindowsMoldingWidth;
public static double InchesDoorsHeight, InchesDoorsLength, InchesDoorsMoldingWidth;
public static String WindowsMoldingColorOrWhite, DoorsMoldingColorOrWhite;
public static double WindowsMoldingCostPerQuart = 0;
public static double DoorsMoldingCostPerQuart = 0;
public static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    UserInputWallsAndCeiling();
    UserInputWindows();
    UserInputDoors();
}
public static void UserInputWallsAndCeiling()
{
    System.out.println("What is the room height in inches? ");
    InchRoomHeight = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("What is the room width in inches? ");
    InchRoomWidth  = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("What is the room length in inches? ");
    InchRoomWidth = scan.nextDouble();
}
public static void UserInputWindows()
{
    System.out.println("How many windows are in the room? ");
    NumberOfWindows = scan.nextDouble();
    if(NumberOfWindows > 0)
        {
            System.out.println("What are the windows height in inches? ");
            InchesWindowsHeight = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("What are the windows length in inches? ");
            InchesWindowsLength = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("What are the windows molding width in inches? ");
            InchesWindowsMoldingWidth = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Is the windows molding color or white? ");

            boolean WindowsTrue = false;
            while (!WindowsTrue)
                {
                    System.out.println("Is the doors molding color or white? ");
                    DoorsMoldingColorOrWhite = scan.nextLine();
                    if ( WindowsMoldingColorOrWhite.equals("color"))
                        {
                            WindowsMoldingCostPerQuart = 12.50; 
                            WindowsTrue = true;
                        }
                    else if (WindowsMoldingColorOrWhite.equals("white"))
                        {
                            WindowsMoldingCostPerQuart = 9.50;
                            WindowsTrue = true;
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Please enter if the molding is color or white");
                        }
                }
        }
}
public static void UserInputDoors()
{
    System.out.print("How many doors are in the room? ");
    NumberOfDoors = scan.nextDouble();
    if(NumberOfDoors > 0)
        {
            System.out.println("What are the doors height in inches? ");
            InchesDoorsHeight = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("What are the doors length in inches? ");
            InchesDoorsLength = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("What are the doors molding width in inches? ");
            InchesDoorsMoldingWidth = scan.nextDouble();

            boolean DoorsTrue = false; 
            while (!DoorsTrue)
                {
                    System.out.println("Is the doors molding color or white? ");
                    DoorsMoldingColorOrWhite = scan.nextLine();
                    if ( DoorsMoldingColorOrWhite.equals("color"))
                        {
                            DoorsMoldingCostPerQuart = 12.50;
                            DoorsTrue = true;
                        }
                    else if (DoorsMoldingColorOrWhite.equals("white"))
                        {
                            DoorsMoldingCostPerQuart = 9.50; 
                            DoorsTrue = true;
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Please enter if the molding is color or white");
                        }
                 }
            //System.out.print(InchesDoorsHeight + " " + InchesDoorsLength + " " + DoorsMoldingColorOrWhite + " " + DoorsMoldingCostPerQuart)
        }
}
public static void IntchesToFeet()
{
    FeetRoomWidth= InchRoomWidth / 12;
    FeetRoomLength = InchRoomLength / 12;
    FeetRoomHeight = InchRoomHeight / 12;
}
```

}

Comment: What is the error and at what line does it get thrown?

Comment: You really need to improve your method and variable naming.

Comment: how can my variables get any more precise. they literately do not even need a comment because the name tells you  exactly what they do.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple typo ;)

```
System.out.println("Is the doors molding color or white? ");
DoorsMoldingColorOrWhite = scan.nextLine();
if ( WindowsMoldingColorOrWhite.equals("color")) {
        //...
}
```

**Doors**Molding vs **Windows**Molding

If you check the NullPointerException that comes out of this, the line of code #61 is pointing directly at that IF statement that tells you to begin your search at or before that line.:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at PaintEstimate.UserInputWindows(PaintEstimate.java:61)

Comment: Thank you, i appreciate your help a lot. i was laughing pretty hard when i realized what you said. to many redundancies. i was just copying an pasting my code every where and forgot to change one minor detail. thank you again.

Comment: No problem. From the code, I assume you're limited in language concepts you're allowed to use (e.g. tutorial)? If you made the variables "private" instead of "public static", a compiler warning (unused variable) would have told you the error would occur. Also if I find myself copy-pasting more than twice, that's a great time to rethink the design and look for a feature of the language to allow me to be lazier.